# Dimple.js x and y data are in arrays for each chart object in json file. Do I have to reformat all the json files?

Tags: json, angularjs, charts, dimple.js

I have a json file that has a large "Charts" section with many different charts of different names.  Using Dimple.JS I'm trying to build charts directly from the json, but I can't figure out how to get the x and y data in correctly.  I want to plot x[0], y[0]

```
{ "Name": "test", "Charts": [
    {
        "chartName": "Idle Times",
        "disk": 0,
        "OpCode": "Read",
        "xAxis": [0,100,200,300,400,500],
        "yAxis": [337487,8565,11419,9704,7598]
    },
    {
        "chartName": "Idle Times",
        "disk": 0,
        "OpCode": "Read",
        "xAxis": [0,100,200,300,400,500],
        "yAxis": [337487,8565,11419,9704,7598]
    }]
}
```

Here is where the chart is being built, this builds a chart, but with just one point.  When you hover over the chart it shows the x-axis array, and the y-axis array, but it's only charting the first numbers.

```
var data = $rootScope._idleTimes.items;
    console.log(data);
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#idle-times-chart-container", 1000, 500);
    var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "xAxis");
    var y = chart.addCategoryAxis("y", "yAxis");
    y.tickFormat = "%";
    chart.addSeries("OpCode", dimple.plot.bar);
    var myLegend = chart.addLegend(950, 50, 60, 100, "Right");
    chart.draw();
    chart.legends = [];
    svg.selectAll("title_text")
        .data([" "])
        .enter()
        .append("text")
            .attr("x", 499)
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return 90 + i * 14; })
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .style("font-size", "10px")
            .style("color", "Black")
            .text(function (d) { return d; });
    var filterValues = dimple.getUniqueValues(data, "OpCode");
    myLegend.shapes.selectAll("rect")
        .on("click", function (e) {
            var hide = false;
            var newFilters = [];
            filterValues.forEach(function (f) {
                if (f === e.aggField.slice(-1)[0]) {
                    hide = true;
                } else {
                    newFilters.push(f);
                }
            });
            if (hide) {
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.2);
            } else {
                newFilters.push(e.aggField.slice(-1)[0]);
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.8);
            }
            filterValues = newFilters;
            chart.data = dimple.filterData(data, "OpCode", filterValues);
            chart.draw(1000);
        });
```

My question is, do I need to reformat the json file so there is one record per line?  Something like this:

```
{"chartName":"Idle Times", "disk":0, "OpCode":"Read","xAxis":0, "yAxis":1234},
{"chartName":"Idle Times", "disk":0, "OpCode":"Read","xAxis":100, "yAxis":1234},
{"chartName":"Idle Times", "disk":0, "OpCode":"Read","xAxis":200, "yAxis":1234},
{"chartName":"Idle Times", "disk":0, "OpCode":"Read","xAxis":300, "yAxis":1234},
{"chartName":"Idle Times", "disk":0, "OpCode":"Read","xAxis":400, "yAxis":1234},
{"chartName":"Idle Times", "disk":0, "OpCode":"Read","xAxis":500, "yAxis":1234},
{"chartName":"Idle Times", "disk":0, "OpCode":"Read","xAxis":600, "yAxis":1234}
```

Or is there a way with angular, dimple, or some other javascript to use my current json files?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid if you want to use dimple you will need to reformat the data exactly as you describe. Either in your source, or at runtime depending on your requirements.  You may also want to add some kind of identifier to disaggregate your bubbles by.  A bubble is drawn for every distinct value of the dimension(s) specified in the first parameter in the addSeries method so in this case you will only get 1 bubble per OpCode value, which is probably not what you want. Alternatively you could pass the x and y values in:

```
chart.addSeries(["xAxis", "yAxis", "OpCode"], dimple.plot.bubble);
```

This will work as long as there are no duplicate pairs of x, y and OpCode values in your data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Now I just need to figure out how to reformat the json into single records for each x,y value.  I'll do some searching around and post a new question if I can't figure it out.